# Make Multiple Activites Landscape If App started as Landscape

Tags: android, orientation, android-orientation, landscape-portrait

### What is Problem?

if app started as portrait then make activity as portrait , otherwise landscape , but don't detect sensor based or used based rotation otherwise.

### My Solution:

Make variable **isPortrait** in application class and detect orientation in onCreate of Application class then use this variable in all activites to detect what orientation to use.

### Problem in My Solution:

No Idea how can I change different configuration layouts and map them accordingly in this scenario , what if user change it orientation to landscape after app started in portrait ? is there any **ActivityInfo** flag to achieve this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your activity tag in manifest

```
 android:configChanges="orientation"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mainfest within the atvitity tag add below code

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

and in ur activity override onConfiguration method like below

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    log.e("onConfigurationChanged", "screen orientation change");
}
```